# Printing mysqli query results

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to print the results of a php query my php code is:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'conect.php';
$resultlog = mysqli_query("SELECT * from cpi ,$con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultlog))
print $row;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

but it result an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: change mysqli_query("SELECT * from cpi ,$con) to mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from cpi"); and try.

Comment: You forgot to give the finishing quotation and also you need to declare connection before the query string.

Comment: 'Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource' error received

Comment: it should be mysqli_fetch_array not mysql_fetch_array. dont mix up mysql with mysqli

Comment: i am new to my sql. what is finishing quotation ?

Comment: you wrote the sql like "SELECT * from cpi . you started the quotation (") but didn't finished it. So it will be like "SELECT * from cpi".

Comment: Do you want to print the results as an array?

Comment: plz check my solution and let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'conect.php';
$resultArray = array();
$resultlog = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from cpi");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultlog)){
  $resultArray[] = $row;
}
mysqli_close($con);
print_r($resultArray);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the DB connection comes first in `mysqli` plus, there's a missing quote.

You're also mixing APIs.

Then add the proper bracing.

```
$resultlog = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from cpi") or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultlog)){
print $row;
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Make sure your DB connection which is not shown, is in fact `mysqli` and not `mysql`, nor PDO.

**None of those APIs intermix.**

However, just doing a `print $row` may probably not show you what you like to get.

Therefore, you may need to elaborate on that.

You're probably wanting to do something like:

```
echo $row['your_column_name'].'<br />';
```

or as Ghost stated:

`print $row[0];` or `print $row['column_name']`

---

*"Its working fine. But can we print all result through one command?"*

Yes, like this:

```
$resultlog = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from cpi") or die(mysqli_error($con));

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultlog);
    foreach($row as $r) {
    echo $r . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: @user2740125 yes thats natural as `$row` is another array result, you need to access its indices, either `$row[0]` or `$row['column_name']`

Comment: @Ghost Yep. I used part of your example in your comment in my answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no prob man, its just supplemental info. this should get it going

Comment: Its working fine. But can we print all result through one command?

Comment: @user2740125 if you want to echo it all, you may need to use just `->fetch_assoc()` then foreach the `$row` inside the while. since `fetch_row()` will have both numeric and associative indices that will duplicate its column set

Comment: @Ghost why not use an array bro?

Comment: @user2740125 *"Its working fine. But can we print all result through one command?"* - Yes, reload to see my edit near the bottom.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes if you use foreach to loop and echo `$row` with `fetch_array()` you'll get duplicate results. here is a visualization http://pastebin.com/aibRBP9t

Comment: @Ghost Oh well, can't win them all. I guess I'll have to take less time at the supermarket lineup.

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol. well whatever works for the op, i just don't think you can use `print_r()` values to present it in a table, most likely i think the OP's going to use this one most cases

Comment: @Ghost My browser was being funky with me, so I did not deliver the goods on time, as it were (excusez-moi haha). No biggie, you know and I know that we're in this for the greater good ;) I like dotting the i's and crossing the t's - just like you. Giving the entire reason why code is failing is beneficial for all. Someone who visits the question will see for themselves.

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually for me explaining and learning how did it went wrong is more beneficial than having just a working code

Comment: @Ghost You said it brother. Couldn't have put it any better myself. *Cheers* (I did edit my commment above to that effect).

Comment: @Fred-ii- brother, I dont see any wrong in my answer. All "user2740125" asked is to print his query results using one command and i gave him what came into my mind. I dont see anything related to "present it in a table" in "user2740125" question. And also what is the meaning of this part "Giving the entire reason why code is failing is beneficial for all. Someone who visits the question will see for themselves."?? We are all here to help others, not to bite. Thnx.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes What I meant by that is, when we explain why the OP's code failed, then the OP will have learned from the mistakes, and if someone else visits the question/answers, will also know why.